# How to get client full url in AWS lambda through AWS gateway requested by <script src="***"> tag

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using html script tag to ping AWS gateway endpoint to trigger a function in AWS lambda.

In this lambda function, I need to retrieve the original client's full url.
I can get referer data but can't figure out how to get the full url.

I tried to see if there is "origin" info in "event" object but there is no such data.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: "console.log(" +JSON.stringify(event) +","+JSON.stringify(context) +")"
  };  
}
```

Here is the client code that pings the http api gateway
index.html

```
<html>
  <script src="http api gateway endpoint" defer async />
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Now how can I get the client full url in lambda function?

Comment: FYI: Amazon AWS is down right now, so you may occur problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information sent in a referrer header is restricted for [security reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Referer_header:_privacy_and_security_concerns). You can adjust this with [a header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) or the `referrerpolicy` attribute.

Note that the `<script>` element is **not** a void element. The end tag is mandatory.

```
<script src="http api gateway endpoint" defer async referrerpolicy"unsafe-url"></script>
```

You could also generate the `<script>` element dynamically and pass data from `window.location` in the query string.

Comment: thank you! it worked!  I am trying to download JS file stored in S3 based on origin url and run the script dynamically.  However, it seems like this way of doing compromises security by exposing referer.. Do you have any other recommended way of achiving this type of requirement?

Comment: "However, it seems like this way of doing compromises security by exposing referer." — Which is why you need to be careful who you expose it to (and why using the attribute to do it for one specific element is safer than doing it globally)

Comment: " Do you have any other recommended way of achiving this type of requirement?" — See the last paragraph of this answer… but the net result is the same so you don't get any security benefits doing it that way.